# Upload to Artifactory with different artifact name, using JFrog CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Here's how you upload an artifact with a different name using curl:

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<KEY>" -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/<TARGET_REPO>/custom_artifact_name.zip" -T original_artifact_name.zip
```

But how do you do this with the jfrog cli? Here's what I have so far:

```
jfrog rt u original_artifact_name.zip <TARGET_REPO> --url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory" --apikey="<KEY>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include the artifact name in the target repo parameter:

```
jfrog rt u original_artifact_name.zip <TARGET_REPO>/custom_artifact_name.zip --url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory" --apikey="<KEY>"
```

See the documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles) for more info.